# How to constantly run a python script on a Webserver

Tags: python, django

I have just coded a trading algorithm and some analytics software for the stock market which in itself works fine.

Since my computer is not always running or internetconnection is not running perfectly I would like to source the script out and put it on a Webserver for example, where it would run all day and night.

Do you guys now I could do that?

I would also like to build a user interface using django to monitor live performance.

Does anybody know what would be necessary to implement these steps?

Thanks in advance and kind regards

Marcel Kresse

Comment: there are many cloud service providers.. go through aws, ibm bluemix or google's cloud computing, they provide virtual machines to get your job done.

Answer (score 1):

This is very general question and the answer is close to "sky is the limit". As mentioned above, any cloud service provider will do.

Most (if not all) clouds have dedicated images for web servers and Django deployments. Have fun.